# Problems with virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

Under `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts` I have the following installed:
-easy install
-pip
-virtualenv

However, whenever i go to activate my virtualenv in the following directory `C:\Users\username\djangotest`     i type in the command line the following code: `C:\Python27\python -m venv myvenv`  and i get a not recognized as internal or external command response.  I am following the setup steps on http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/index.html

Am i setting virtual env in the wrong filepath?

Thanks

Comment: Does `C:\Python27\python.exe` exist? (Somebody has to ask..)

Comment: yes, its in the C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2 directory level, not in scripts.

Comment: When I used to dev on Windows, I used: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win

Comment: @Brandon, how do i set my virtual env after running that? i want to make sure i set it correctly. I did install the wrapper successfully with that code.

Comment: It's nearly the same as virtualenvwrapper for Linux / OS X. Look in the "Main Commands" section on the home page I linked to.

Comment: *Is* it `C:\Python27\python.exe`? Not `C:\Python27\whatever\python.exe`? Because the error semi-shown indicates that cmd.exe itself cannot find the executable, which generally indicates an incorrect path.. if `python` itself is in the PATH then just omit the start.

Comment: Well, *find* and *verify* the location :)

Comment: I have python installed through a 3rd party software in ArcGIS. I changed the env variable so i don't have to call the whole python.exe directory. just call python somefilename.py. The location is what i said earlier. just a layer deeper than usual because of the 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serve me right, only python3.3 support -m to create virtualenv. Version prior to that you have to use virtualenv to install virtual enviroment.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

**Update:**

```
C:
CD\
virtualenv -p C:\Python27\python.exe MyVirtualEnv
```

That should create a "MyVirtualEnv" virtualenv folder in your c: drive.

Comment: I have virtualenv installed but can't get to set my path to virtualenv correctly.